# Header with video background, position not working in safari

Tags: html, css, video, background, header

I am trying to make a header with a video background. I've inserted a video in html and made the video's z-index -100 in css.

It works very well in google chrome for now, but if i open my website in safari, the video background's position is totally wrong.

I can't figure out to fix this, so both browsers will show the same.

Website can be seen here: http://www.chatroom.guru

This is my html:
            `<header>
            <video autoplay loop poster="polina.jpg" id="bgvid">
                    <source src="/img/headerbgvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="bgvid">
                </video>
            <div class="container">
               <p id="title1">Connect with the world today!</p>
               <p id="title2">Join the world's best social chatroom for gamers.</p>`

This is my CSS:

```
video#bgvid {
position: absolute;
margin-top: -90px;
width: 100%;
z-index: -100;}
```

Hope someone can help me out! 
Thank you

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to absolute position your video? I think you could leave the video and just absolute position your `.container`. (careful to target the correct `.container` though)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I still cannot get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `object-fit:cover` to your video style:

```
video#bgvid {
    object-fit:cover;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Ok I think it would be best to basically start over. There is a lot of styling you have going on here. Also, your HTML is not valid to begin with. For example your `nav` `ul`s are improperly nested. It shouldn't be hard to do what you want, but it may be impossible with your current code. Try again and keep it simple and valid. Then style the absolute minimum.